# What should be the relationship between those entities?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have models: User, UserFolowing and UserProfile
In which Entity should be the collection of followers(UserFollowing)
and which reletionship should be beetwen User and UserProfile
This is my entities:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
public class UserProfile
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public string Image { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<UserFollowing> Followings { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<UserFollowing> Followers { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }
}
public class UserFollowing
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    
    public Guid FollowingId { get; set; }
    
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: you got the `ICollection<UserFollowing> Followers` and the relation  _beetwen_ _User_ _and_ _UserProfile_ is set in those classes already

Comment: you can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships)